# How to update ssh configuration files in NixOs

Tags: nixos

I've been playing with NixOs and was wondering how one can modify a config file.
For example I tried to modify the ssh configuration file `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` (to allow root ) but
I can't save the file, as it's only a link.
I understand that modifying a file manually is not the way to do (because the system needs
be aware of the modification), so what is the NixOs way to do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [`programs.ssh` options](https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/options.html#opt-programs.ssh.agentTimeout).

Also note there's an `extraConfig` for further text in ssh_config.

Comment: Does that mean that config file can't be altered manually but needs to be generated by derivations ?

Comment: Yes, unless you tell nixos to not generate such file. Probably `environment.etc."ssh_config".enable = false` or such.